# How can crystal symmetry operations be used to reduce the number of unique properties of a solid?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals

Can anyone please give an example or a reference which shows how crystal point groups and symmetry operations can be used to reduce the number of parameters describing the property of a crystal, leaving only the unique parameters?

Comment: The most direct that I can recall is the elasticity tensors. The wikipedia article on linear elasticity has some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a classical example is electrical conductivity and resistivity (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Tensor_equations_for_anisotropic_materials)), or any physical quantity which is described in the anisotropic case by a tensor (see also elasticity tensor as suggested in the comments by [Jon Custer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/38675/jon-custer)).
Consider the Ohm's law in the anisotropic case
$$
J_{i}=\sigma_{ij} E_j, \qquad E_i=\rho_{ij} J_j
$$
The conductivity $\sigma$ and resistivity $\rho$ are 3x3 matrix (tensors), for example
$$
\sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{xx}&\sigma_{xy}&\sigma_{xz}\\
\sigma_{yx}&\sigma_{yy}&\sigma_{yz}\\
\sigma_{zx}&\sigma_{zy}&\sigma_{zz}\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and where $\rho=\sigma^{-1}$ is the matrix inverse of the conductivity $\sigma$.

If the crystal lattice is cubic, directions $x$, $y$, and $z$ are equivalent, and therefore the physical properties are isotropic.
In this case one has $\sigma_{xx}=\sigma_{yy}=\sigma_{zz}$, and $\sigma_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$, and therefore one has
$$
\sigma=\sigma_0\mathbf{1},\qquad \rho=\rho_0\mathbf{1},
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the identity matrix and $\rho_0=1/{\sigma_0}$.
In this case the Ohm's law reduces to the standard vector form 
$$\mathbf{J}=\sigma_0 \mathbf{E},\qquad \mathbf{E}=\rho_0 \mathbf{J}$$
The physical description in the anisotropic case needs 3x3 parameters (the components of the conductivity tensor). The cubic symmetry reduces this parameters to just one, $\sigma_0$.

PS: I've found this book [Symmetry, Group Theory, and the Physical Properties of Crystals](https://books.google.it/books?id=ojq5BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA226&l#v=onepage&q&f=false) by R C Powell.